# How does the ZX80 keyboard avoid ghosting and masking?

Tags: diodes, keyboard, matrix

I believe that a keyboard matrix needs a diode on *each* key to avoid ghosting and masking.

http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/How_Key_Matrices_Works/

The ZX80 (and probably ZX81) has only a diode for each half-row.

http://searle.hostei.com/grant/zx80/zx80circuitAnnotated.pdf

How does this work?

Comment: Perhaps you've answered your own question - without diodes on each key, the possibility for ghosting and masking exists.

Comment: From what I remember from 1987, ZX81 keys were really hard to press. It was possibly the worst keyboard I used. So I think the whole thing was prevented by making it impossible to attempt in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyboard is not designed to handle ghosting and masking...
(If Q,R,F were pressed the computer would also see the A key as well.)

The diodes are there to keep the cost down (The diodes are so that the keys won't force another Address line low, which would crash the computer) - in other computers a buffer IC(s) and better address decoding would be used, but to keep costs down the diodes can be used - but this 'wastes' addresses (not that it matters on a computer like this)

How the keyboard works

```
           A8   A9  A10  A11  A12  A13  A14  A15  Keyboard layout
            |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    K4 -    V    G    T    5    6    Y    H    B
    K3 -    C    F    R    4    7    U    J    N
    K2 -    X    D    E    3    8    I    K    M
    K1 -    Z    S    W    2    9    O    L    .
    K0 -  Shift  A    Q    1    0    P   NL  Space

(I'm using K0-K5 to be the inputs to IC 10)
Lines K0,K1,K2,K3,K4 are pulled to 5V by R13,R14,R15,R16,R17
```

Suppose you want to see if the A key is pressed

In Machine code you
would do the following

```
    LD BC,FEFF - Just set A9 to Low
    IN A,(C)   - Read keys A,S,D,F,G
    BIT 0,A    - if Bit 0 (D0) is low then set the Z flag
    JP Z,xxxx  - if the Z flag is set then jump to xxxx
```

The Value in BC is put onto the Address lines when then IN A,(C) command is executed, The value should be chosen so that only 1 address line is low at this time - the value I chose will set only A9 to logic low.

K0 can only be pulled low when Shift,A,Q,1,0,P,New Line or Space is pressed (And then only if the correct Address line is pulled low - in this case only A9 is low so only the A key will cause K0 to go low (Ignore ghosting at the moment)

IC 10 is activated by the KBD signal line from the IO decoder, this then put the the signals from K0-K5  onto the cpu data bus D0-D5 (I'm ignoring D6-D7 as I'm only dealing with the keyboard) - the IN A,(C) command put this value into register A,

we then use the Bit command to see if D0 is low - if so Set the Z flag...

To keep cost down, the logic levels are 'inverted' - this means that the computer looks for a low/0 for a key press, and not a High/1 (Most ICs can pull a signal low more easily than pull a signal high) - it is cheaper to rewrite the code the CPU uses than add an extra IC to invert the signal levels to the CPU - They made the ZX80 as cheap as possible - and it was about 1/2 the cost of any other computer with basic at the time...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe that design doesn't address ghosting and masking. It's not a problem if the user presses one button at a time.

Comment: The membrane keyboards used on these computers were not exactly designed for high-speed touch typing, so these issues were simply not a design criterion.

Answer (score 3):

That circuit uses some address lines to enable keyboard reading. Some other address lines (not part of the enable circuit) determine which columns (note the s) are read: a low address line can, via a keyboard switch, pull one of the inputs of IC10 low. This depends on the property of LS TTL inputs that a floating input is seen as high.

The diodes in the circuit are needed to prevent that pressed keys could connect an address line to another address line, which would not be a good idea. They are not there to prevent ghosting/masking. The ZX80 had a membrane keyboard, it was hard enough to press one key, multi key press detection as not a feature of this beast.